# Reviews rating in Magento2

Tags: magento2.2, product-review

I have 2 product review for same product.

I can get the rating summary for product.

```
$this->_reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
           echo $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();exit;
```

But I need to get rating summary for each review for same product.

How to do that ..

Thanks

Comment: May not be most optimum way but you can do it via custom query.

Comment: You product is configurable?

Comment: Yes .........................